# How to statically assert that floating points are IEEE-754 in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

I would like to make assumptions about the representation of floating points, and I would like to verify at compile time using a `static_assert` whether the floating point representations are IEEE-754 since I transfer them through the network.

How could I make sure using a `static_assert` that the `float` and `double` types are in the format specified in IEEE-754?

Comment: If all you care about is the representation of floating-point numbers, not full conformance to IEEE-754 behavior, then testing the characteristics defined in `<float.h>` may be useful. `FLT_RADIX` should be 2, `FLT_MANT_DIG` should be 24 (and `DBL_MANT_DIG` should be 53), `FLT_MIN_EXP` should be −125 (−1021 for `DBL`), and `FLT_MAX_EXP` should be 128 (1024 for `DBL`). (The exponents are off by one from IEEE-754 documentation because uses a significand in [1, 2), but C bases it on [½, 1).)

Comment: You may also want to check `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` and `DBL_HAS_SUBNORM`, which should be 1. However, Apple LLVM 9.1.0 with clang-902.0.39.2 is not setting these, in spite of them being defined to be 1 in `<float.h>`. The compiler appears to be using some built-in `float.h` instead of the actual file in the SDK.

Comment: Touching a bit on behavior, you can consider `FLT_ROUNDS` (defined to be 1 if the rounding mode is to-nearest) and `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, which you would like to be 0 for “evaluate all operations and constants just to the range and precision of the type.” That one may be the most troublesome of the above; it is not uncommon for implementations to use −1 (indeterminable) or 1 or 2 (evaluate using `double` or `long double`). There may be compiler switches to adjust this, so you may be able to get `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` 0 with a switch.

Comment: And check that the radix is 2 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

C99 has a macro `__STD_IEC_559__` in order to check if the floating point representation comply with IEEE 754.

The issue is that some compilers do not define this macro.

Acording to this [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) you could check like follows:

```
#ifndef __STDC_IEC_559__ 
puts("Warning: __STDC_IEC_559__ not defined. IEEE 754 floating point not fully supported."); 
// #endif
```

Comment: That would be awesome! It could be a clean solution if compilers added it sometime in future. I am afraid it doesn't help me much right now if it doesn't work in practice :-(.

Comment: `__STDC_IEC_559__` does not check if the floating-point representation conforms to IEEE 754. It asserts that the C implementation conforms to IEC 60559, effectively IEEE 754—meaning not just the floating-point representation but also the operations and other behavior. Few implementations fully conform, so few implementations define `__STDC_IEC_559__`. But many implementations use IEEE-754 representations (formats). So `__STDC_IEC_559__` is not a useful way of testing what the representation is nor of determining how well an implementation conforms.

Comment: Also note it is `__STDC_IEC_559__`, not `__STD_IEC_559__`.